# Is there a way my rasa chatbot can know the logged in user full name and greet him?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

I'm currently working on Rasa framework to develop a chatbot. I want to know how do i greet the user with his/her own name. For instance, the user will login to the application and then when he clicks on the chatbot icon it should know who logged in and greet the user. Is there a way i can achieve this.?

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully  worked with HTTP API calls as well. So fetching data from Database isn't hard. My assumption on how to achieve this is through session data. I believe there has to be something in the session data where i can get the username.

Answer (score 1):

When a user clicks on the chatbot icon, you will send a query to the rasa framework. You can add the name of the user to the query, and in the action server of rasa, use the name for greeting the user.